# If you are extending a class in python how do you import another class and use it?

Tags: python, mysql, class, scrapy

So I'm playing around with Scrapy which is a set of classes that allows you to do web scraping and I wanted to throw some data into a data base, but I'm having truble importing the MySQL methods while extending the scrapy library.

here is my code:

```py
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import Request
import MySQLdb

class test(BaseSpider): #if i don't extend the class the MySQL works, but the Scrapy functionallity does not. 
    name = "test"
    allowed_domains = ["some-website.com"] #i know this is probibly not a real websit... just using it as an example. 
    start_urls = [
        "http://some-website.com",
    ]

    db = MySQLdb.connect(
       host = 'localhost',
       user = 'root',
       passwd = '',
       db = 'scrap'
    )
    #cursor = db.cursor()

    def parse(self, response):
       hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
       for title in hxs.select('//a[@class="title"]/text()').extract():
            print title
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `scrap`.`shows` (id, title) VALUES (NULL , '"+title+"');")
```

I am still a noob to python so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you fix your indentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something is wrong with your [architecture](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.14/topics/architecture.html).

Spider's job is to parse pages, extract data and put it into an [Item](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.14/topics/items.html). It is [pipeline's](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.14/topics/item-pipeline.html) job to save the data from an Item in a database:

> Typical use for item pipelines are:
>
> - cleansing HTML data
> - validating scraped data (checking that the items    contain certain fields)
> - checking for duplicates (and dropping them)
> - storing the scraped item in a database

So, make a pipeline, put its path into [settings.py](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.14/topics/settings.html#item-pipelines). Try to work with the DB in that pipeline.

I think you need to read the [tutorial](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.14/intro/tutorial.html) and see the [examples](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.14/intro/examples.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for this tip. as I said before I'm still a noob when it comes to python. I will look into building a pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you shold define `self.cursor` ?
In this way the cursor will be accesible on the class methods.
I do not know about scrapy, but most probably you should do that on the `__init__` method or on a `get_cursor` method of the class test (that probably you should rename as Test)